# Microsoft Graph API - Expand User Photos

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to grab all user information using the Microsoft Graph API and I was wondering if there was a more concise way of also grabbing a users photos to replace what I am currently doing.

I am currently doing the following;

1. Grab user details by calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=manager`
   **NOTE:** I am using the beta API as I cannot seem to get the manager data back otherwise.
2. Iterate over users and then for each user call `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photos`
3. For each photo returned I am then;

   1. Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photos/{photo_id}` to get the meta data (e.g. id, height and width). **NOTE:** I have found the height and width on the initial **photos** are not always correct whereas they are on this call (so I use this one only for the details)
   2. Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user_id}/photos/{photo_id}/$value` to get the image.

This results in lots of individual API calls on top of the users query;

- for every user a call to get array of photos
- for every photo one to get the photo metadata
- for every photo one to get the photo binary data.

This could quickly get substantial with a large organisation utilizing multiple profile pictures per person for different sizes.

Is there a way of expanding the photo data within the initial users call to avoid having to do all of these additional API calls?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things here John.

1. Calling `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos` API is basically a way for you to see what photo sizes are available. You can optimize which size you want, based on your experience - for example if it's a mobile device you might select the smallest (or second smallest size).  If it's for a desktop device, you might select the largest size. Requesting `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo` (note the singular) will get the metadata for the largest available photo. The smaller sizes are scaled versions of the largest photo. In some circumstances, only one size is available. Please see details [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get). So I'm not sure why you need to get every profile photo size (it's the same photo, but different sizes).
2. You should take a look at batching to make multiple API calls in one round-trip. Please see this [batching topic](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching).  NOTE: Batching is still in preview, but will GA soon.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan,
Thanks for the response.

The reason I am trying to gather all sizes together is I am centralizing and joining data from various data sources and then that data is being used external from it's original source. In this case I have scenarios where different sizes of profile picture would be useful. 
I guess I could just access the largest via the the singular call you outlined above and then adjust the size programmatically in Java or such like?

The batching would certainly reduce the number of individual requests I was doing, I will give it a go and see how it goes.

Comment: Were you able to find any workaround to get user Profile photo using MS Graph API . I am working on same POC and had to follow same number of APIS , if there is any alternate way to get users Profile photo along with User/People API , It will help lot.

Appreciate your help in advance.